# heap space issue when extracting PDFs

Tags: java, pdf, text, memory-leaks

I've spent a lot of time on this.
I have an application that extracts text from lots of docs and pdfs and puts the extracted information in a simple Access database. I control it fmr a Swing interface. It has a significant memory leak.

Having finally used IBMs [HeapSpaceAnalyzer](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communitystart?communityUuid=4544bafe-c7a2-455f-9d43-eb866ea60091) I've found that most of the heap is being occupied by instances from a library I use call [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)

[image]

I have nulled all the Hashes and arrays in my code with no effect on pdfbox

I've seen others with similar heap space issues to this one and it's been suggested that PDFFont.clearResources() is useful- but it's not been of benefit to me - I usually put this in at the end of processing one document but the heap maintains these references regardless.

If I leave the application alone with no processing for a while I get a slightly different kind of memory leak:
[image]

Either way pdfBox just seems to be leaking away and I dont think increasing the heap space usage is going to work. Does anyone know how to clear pdfBox's references? It just seems to leak away.

Comment: Pdfbox is not high art, only the data structures can become complex with many details and cross-linking. The latter might be problematic. I assume you have checked the closing of all pdfbox things, reader, document or whatever. Take the code in a separate app and look. If StackOverflow yields no solution.

Comment: Do you get OOM exceptions or just observe a higher than expected memory usage?

Comment: Your images look like it's the fonts which are probably cached for reuse. Maybe there's a way to clear that font cache somehow.

Comment: I do get OOM if I'm running hundreds of files but at the moment no OOM. I have closed everything i possibly can. My data structures are complex but I null them early but pdfbox perhaps caches them

Comment: Hiw can I empty the font cache?

Comment: Can I just ignore the fonts? I'm not sure why I need a font cache as I'm just extracting raw text

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using?

Comment: I was using pdfbox 2.0.3 bur I am also using tika 1.12

Comment: I think you should delete this question, as the other one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910781/remove-pdfont-caching-with-apache-tika is about the same problem and more narrow.