# Remove PDFont caching with Apache tika

Tags: pdfbox, apache-tika

I am trying to extract text only from a number of different coduments (rtf doc pdf). I naturally turned to Apache Tika because it can autodetect the document and extract text accordingly. I am only interested in the text and not formatting etc.

My application ends up with a big memory leak and on investigating it, this is coming from caching from PDFFont class from the PDFBox dependency. I am not interesting in caching Fontmetrics and other Font formatting issues from pdfs as I want to only extract the text.

I am using tika 1.12. Does anyone know how to get around this cahcing issue. This is how I am using Autodetect:

```
        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();

        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File(child.getPath()));
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();              
        parser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, context);
        String s=null;
        s =handler.toString();
        handler=null;
        context=null;
        inputstream.close();
        PDFont.clearResources();
```

Comment: PDFBox 2.0.3 has solved some problems with leaking fonts. You need to use the latest TIKA version and use PDFBox 2.0.3 with it.

Comment: See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fudged a workaround and just called `System.gc();` everytime the file had finished being processed which works a treat but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: This is weird, the JDK is assumed to do a gc() anyway when free space gets small. To do further investigation the TIKA people would need the file(s). And my bet is that it is the problem that was solved in PDFBOX 2.0.3 because that one did deal with fonts.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Can you please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615758/memory-leak-issue-with-pdfbox